# How do I create a vector that holds objects?

Tags: c++, object, vector

I'm trying to create a vector that can hold several already existing objects but i'm having trouble with it. In visual studio it says "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier".

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct test {
    int id;

    test(int i) {
        id = i;
    }
};

test obj1(1);
test obj2(2);
test obj3(3);

std::vector<test> egg;

egg.push_back(obj1);
egg.push_back(obj2);
egg.push_back(obj3);

int main() {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue with that program is that all of your code is outside of the main method, and thus the compiler doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write *expression statements* such as `egg.push_back(obj1);` at *file/namespace scope*, in contrast with *declarations/definitions* such as `test obj1(1);`. *Expression statements* can only be used at *block scope*, i.e. inside a function body. For example

```
int main() {
    egg.push_back(obj1);
    egg.push_back(obj2);
    egg.push_back(obj3);
}
```

Also avoid using global variables and put all variable declarations/definitions in a local scope as well:

```
int main() {
    test obj1(1);
    test obj2(2);
    test obj3(3);

    std::vector<test> egg;

    egg.push_back(obj1);
    egg.push_back(obj2);
    egg.push_back(obj3);
}
```

Also, unrelated to question, use the *member initializer list* of the constructor to *initialize* members, rather than *assigning* to the members in the constructor body:

```
test(int i) : id(i) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As zach has said, there is code outside of your main method. `std::vector<test> egg;` is allowed outside of `int main` but a function like `egg.push_back(obj1);` is not

revised code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct test {
    int id;

    test(int i) {
        id = i;
    }
};

test obj1(1);
test obj2(2);
test obj3(3);

std::vector<test> egg;

int main() {
    egg.push_back(obj1); //moved to main
    egg.push_back(obj2); //moved to main
    egg.push_back(obj3); //moved to main
}
```